# Disable submit button with md-select

Tags: angular

What I have here is I have a md-select in the form, and the md-option could be manually selected or autofilled by some other component. The question is the submit button is disabled probably if I manually fill all the required inputs, however if I using the other component to autofill these fields, sometimes there is no value for the md-select, and the button still able to click.

```
                  <md-select [userData]="'patient.title'" placeholder="Title" class="full-width" name="title" [(ngModel)]="user.title" required>
                    <md-option *ngFor="let title of titles" [value]="title.Label">
                      {{ title.Label }}
                    </md-option>
                  </md-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ng-disabled directive like this:

Create boolean variable disableUserDataSelect. In your code set disableDataSelect to false when there is no value for the md-select (or in general when you want do desable the selection). then change you html for the md-select adding *ng-disabled="disableUserDataSelect""* like this:

```
              <md-select ng-disabled="disableUserDataSelect" [userData]="'patient.title'" placeholder="Title" class="full-width" name="title" [(ngModel)]="user.title" required>
                <md-option *ngFor="let title of titles" [value]="title.Label">
                  {{ title.Label }}
                </md-option>
              </md-select>
```

In this way your selection will be disabled when you want.

Check this question:

[How to disable md-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472309/how-to-disable-md-select)